# help on fiscal calendar class

Tags: c#

I am looking for a fiscal calendar class rather than having to roll my own.
So far I haven’t had much luck in finding something that suits me.

I am relatively new to the idea of a fiscal calendar and to programming for that matter.

The dates that my company uses for its fiscal reporting are strange to me, I can’t seem to make any sense of it and I am suspecting that the financial department uses tea leaves and chicken entrails to create the calendar. I have asked, several times but no answer.

Details :
Our fiscal year starts on July 1 every year. Our current year is named FY11.

The dates of our fiscal year are as follows:

```
 Jul    30-Jun-10    to 27-Jul-10
Aug 28-Jul-10    to 28-Aug-10
Sep 29-Aug-10    to 27-Sep-10
Oct 28-Sep-10    to 26-Oct-10
Nov 27-Oct-10    to 27-Nov-10
Dec 28-Nov-10    to 28-Dec-10
Jan 29-Dec-10    to 26-Jan-11
Feb 27-Jan-11    to 23-Feb-11
Mar 24-Feb-11    to 28-Mar-11
Apr 29-Mar-11    to 26-Apr-11
May 27-Apr-11    to 28-May-11
Jun 29-May-11    to 29-Jun-11
```

The next year will be different  . I have a number of years into the future.

Anyways,  I have pretty much given up on trying to find   example code that I could work from and I am asking this forum for any advice that you could give a beginner  programmer on what approach you would take to creating a fiscal_calendar class.

I suspect that I will never find the true rational behind the financial departments financial calendar creation methodology and will be stuck with spreadsheets detailing the gregorian to fiscal comparison.

Thanks for any insight you can provide

Comment: +1 for the comment "The dates that my company uses for its fiscal reporting are strange to me, I can’t seem to make any sense of it and I am suspecting that the financial department uses tea leaves and chicken entrails to create the calendar. I have asked, several times but no answer."

Comment: Is there a question here?  What are you trying to accomplish?  You talk about a calendar class but not what you want it to do.

Comment: It looks to me like his questions is "any advice that you could give a beginner programmer on what approach you would take to creating a fiscal_calendar class?"